# How to show own posts if privacy is set to friends

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my SQL query:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT t.tid, t.title, t.time, t.authorid, t.photo, f.fuid, f.myuid, u.username as writer 
      FROM topics as t, friends as f, users as u 
     WHERE cid='$cid' 
       AND u.id=t.authorid 
       AND (
               f.fuid=t.authorid AND f.myuid='$myid' 
               OR
               f.myuid=t.authorid AND f.fuid='$myid'
           ) 
  ORDER BY tid DESC 
     LIMIT $start, $perpage
");
```

I am getting output only when friends post something but not getting anything when I post. My friends are able to view my updates but myself not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more info (sample data, for example), I'd say: try the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT t.tid, t.title, t.time, t.authorid, t.photo, f.fuid, f.myuid, u.username as writer 
      FROM topics as t, friends as f, users as u 
     WHERE cid='$cid' 
       AND u.id=t.authorid 
       AND (
               f.fuid=t.authorid AND f.myuid='$myid' 
               OR
               f.myuid=t.authorid AND f.fuid='$myid'
               OR
               t.autorid='$myid'
           ) 
  ORDER BY tid DESC 
     LIMIT $start, $perpage
");
```

Comment: still getting problem ..help me

Comment: on appliying your code: on increaing friends own posts repeats as when i have 2 frnds my posts repeates 2 times now i have 3 friends my posts repeats 3 times..

Comment: Try using `SELECT DISTINCT`... That should filter out duplicates.

Comment: @PrinceJuGnU, please provide some sample data for us.